Entity Framework Core's BulkInsert doesn't care about nvarchar column length
I'm trying to insert some records with DbContext.BulkInsert, and I have a column that's nvarchar(50), but as soon as I try adding a record where this column is populated with 21 characters it breaks, saying

String or binary data would be truncated in table
'MyTableTemp48c57226Output', column 'MyColumn'. Truncated value:
'湰ԁʨ.(.......ᝰʨ.㨀Ԅʨ.'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

I checked my entity file, configuration file, and this column via SQL Server Management Studio, it says that max is 50 characters everywhere.
I tried changing BulkConfig.BatchSize from default to 1 and int.Max with no success.
The catch is that I have other columns that are nvarchar(50) that work just fine when populated with more than 20 characters, so I checked if I have any triggers or constraints for MyTable.MyColumn column, but I don't.
Original code is not mine, and I'm out of ideas what to look for.
I googled it and I see couple of developers having issues with this, but none of their solutions help me.
I'm not even adding some random characters from crazy encodings. I tried hard coding some values to check this, but the limit is clear, it's because DbContext.BulkInsert thinks that limit on this column is 20, not 50.
Btw, if it means anything, here's how my bulk configuration looks like
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig  
                     { 
                         SetOutputIdentity = true, 
                         BatchSize = 4000, 
                         IncludeGraph = true, 
                         PreserveInsertOrder = true 
                     };

I'm currently testing by adding a single, new, as empty as possible entity so I can focus on this error.
Do you think I could check elsewhere for why DbContext.BulkInsert is not working for this column?
Is this some kind of a limit or a setting I missed for DbContext.BulkInsert?

"I have a column that's nvarchar(50)" you don't. That error is not coming from EF, it comes directly from the database server, so your assertion must be untrue. Double check your table definition, and that you are using the right server, database, schema and table. Also the value might be using double-width encoding so it takes up more than 20 character points.

I quadruple checked before posting and I checked again now, still 50. I'd like it if I was wrong like you suggest, it'd be an easy fix then and you'd feel good about telling me I'm wrong, win-win. I didn't know about the double-width encoding, I'll google it. Thanks!

Is that your actual value you are dealing with? Because that comes out to 19 characters https://dbfiddle.uk/YCqjflDy

Ah, no, that's a totally changed value. My value is something like MySuperLongNameOfTheType. No funny letters, no numbers, just US characters, and I'm not using a strange keyboard language so it's as plain text as it can get with some uppercase characters.

And you are positive it doesn't contain any weird invisible control characters? Can you copy and paste the value exactly into your post?

Probably it fails to create correct temporary table.
